# vueJS hide element in dynamic table row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Job</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
      <td><p class="title">My title</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.job"></td>
      <td><a @click="title()">Remove title</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I wonder how I can toggle a jquery `.hide()` on the `<p class="title">My title</p>` when the remove title link is clicked on.
I dont want to use `v-show` since I am trying to understand how I can target elements within dynamic generated rows in vueJS.

The problem is that there are many rows in my table so every title tag must have a uniqe class and I dont understand how I can hide a specific title on dynamic generated rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done this way using [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-show) directive.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.table',
  data: {
    rows: [
      { showTitle: true, job: 'A' },
      { showTitle: true, job: 'B' },
      { showTitle: true, job: 'C' }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Job</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
      <td><p v-show='row.showTitle' class="title">My title</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.job"></td>
      <td><a @click="row.showTitle = false">Remove title</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

Here is jQuery version but as I already said this is a bad practice.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.table',
  data: {
    rows: [
      { job: 'A' },
      { job: 'B' },
      { job: 'C' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    hideTitle(index) {
      $(this.$refs['title' + index]).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Job</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
      <td><p class="title" :ref="'title' + index">My title</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.job"></td>
      <td><a @click="hideTitle(index)">Remove title</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I want to know how I can do it the jquery way and also how I can target elements within the row being clicked.

Comment: If I only know how I can get the row being clicked and it items within I can apply other things such as changing text labels within the row etc

Comment: Mixing Vue and jQuery should be considered a bad practice.

Comment: Added jQuery version.

Comment: Thanks for the addd jquery! I just felt that the ``v-show`` was a bit "static" since I cant target the row elements. Eg change a placeholder in the dynamic row when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

For conditionally displaying, you can use ***v-show*** directive,document link here :
[v-show doucment](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show).

Hope this can be helpful to you！

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I want to know how I can do it the jquery way and also how I can target elements within the row being clicked.

Comment: If I only know how I can get the row being clicked and it items within I can apply other things such as changing text labels within the row etc

Comment: You can use  $event.target to target element which has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it works. using v-f and title model

**template**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Job</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
      <td v-if="title  === false"><p class="title">My title</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.job"></td>
      <td><a @click="title()">Remove title</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**script**

```
  data () {
        title:false,
},


 methods: {
title(){

        this.title= true
}
}
```

Comment: But this is similar to ``v-show`` I wonder how I could hide the title using jquery? More or less how can I target that specific element in the row. The data is dynamic so there could be multiple rows which means I cant use class identifier

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, mixing jQuery and Vue is not the best idea.  However, if you must, you can use the `event.target` that @flypan mentioned along with some jQuery selectors to get what you want.

I put together a JSFiddle using your HTML as an example of what can be done:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [
        { job: 'A' }, { job: 'B' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    title: function() {
      $title = $(event.target).parent().parent().find("p");
      $($title).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

You would probably want to tighten the selector to find the "p", but this is just an example.  Here's the working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/p5Lpxj5a/